# Building a Treatments Page, What Do I Use?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I am currently building a site for a local day spa and I have hit a dead end in regards to the treatments page. I just don't know what I'm doing, I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of weeks now. Being a newbie to WordPress Theme Development, I'm really struggling with this as I'm not 100% sure of the best method.

This is the layout I'm looking to have:

```
- Treatment Category (Waxing)
    - Treatments Within That Category (Half Leg Wax, Full Leg Wax, etc)
```

I have managed to create a custom post type and taxonomy (assuming this is what I need to do) and I have been successful in create treatment categories and the treatments themselves, but I'm just stuck on how to actually output these to a page.

Here's the code I have used to create the custom post type and taxonomy:

**functions.php**

```
function lds_treatment_cpt() {
   $labels = array(
      'name'                =>  _x( 'Treatment', 'post type general name' ),
      'singular_name'       =>  _x( 'Treatment', 'post type singular name' ),
      'add_new'             =>  _x( 'Add New', 'Treatment' ),
      'add_new_item'        =>  __( 'Add New Treatment' ),
      'edit_item'           =>  __( 'Edit Treatment' ),
      'new_item'            =>  __( 'New Treatment' ),
      'all_items'           =>  __( 'All Treatments' ),
      'view_item'           =>  __( 'View Treatment' ),
      'search_items'        =>  __( 'Search Treatments' ),
      'not_found'           =>  __( 'No Treatments Found' ),
      'not_found_in_trash'  =>  __( 'No Treatments Found in Trash' ),
      'parent_item_colon'   =>  '',
      'menu_name'           =>  'Treatments'
   );

   $supports = array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'author',
      'custom-fields',
      'post-formats',
      'comments',
      'revisions'
   );

   $details = array(
      'labels'          =>  $labels,
      'description'     =>  'Everything you want to know about a treatment',
      'public'          =>  true,
      'menu_position'   =>  5,
      'supports'        =>  $supports,
      'has_archive'     =>  true,
   );
   register_post_type( 'treatment', $details );

}
add_action( 'init', 'lds_treatment_cpt' );


function lds_treatment_taxonomy() {
   $labels = array(
      'name'                =>  _x( 'Treatment Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name'       =>  _x( 'Treatment Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items'        =>  __( 'Search Treatment Categories' ),
      'all_items'           =>  __( 'All Treatment Categories' ),
      'parent_item'         =>  __( 'Parent Treatment Category' ),
      'parent_item_colon'   =>  __( 'Parent Treatment Category:' ),
      'edit_item'           =>  __( 'Edit Treatment Category' ),
      'update_item'         =>  __( 'Update Treatment Category' ),
      'add_new_item'        =>  __( 'Add New Treatment Category' ),
      'new_item_name'       =>  __( 'New Treatment Category' ),
      'menu_name'           =>  __( 'Treatment Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
      'labels'          =>  $labels,
      'hierarchical'    =>  true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'treatment_category', 'treatment', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'lds_treatment_taxonomy', 0 );
```

In a nut shell I need to know how I can output all the treatment categories on to once page and then display the treatments within a particular category on another page (if that makes sense).

I would really appreciate some help with this as I've been stuck on it for way too long.

Thanks

Stu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @N00b pointed out this can go in many answers and needs many concepts digestion.I will try to concise and give a sample answer with little info.

Since you have set **`has_archive`** to true while registering post type , we can see all treatment post-type post on **`example.com/treatment/`**. If we want to change this page to display just taxonomy categories list, we can use template page for this.

Create **`archive-treatment.php`** in the root directory of the theme (If you know how to code and create child themes or the theme is your own ). Example `archive-treament.php` looks like.

**`archive-treatment.php`**

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No treatment categories' ),
        'style'               => 'list',
        'taxonomy'            => 'treatment_category',
        'title_li'            => __( 'Treatment Categories' )
    );
    wp_list_categories($args);
    get_footer();
```

Here [`wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) outputs the categories available in the `treatment_category` taxonomy and check all the arguments available.

If you just want to create page and use shortcodes there are many plugins out there that do this.

**Reference:**

[Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

[wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#source-code)

[Display Posts Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/)